# Can an Apple operator tell you the locations to where your Apple ID was log in at?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

Someone hacked into my Apple ID, and I was just wondering if the operators could tell me the location for the login or at least let me know if the hacker was receiving any of my texts messages. If not I was just going to leave it alone with just changing my password.

Answer (score 1):

To address the second part of your question:
When associating another device to iMessage (to be able to read your iMessages, not sure about the SMS sent by non Apple / iMessage devices) the attacker would've triggered an alert on your device:

[image: imessage activation second device pop up - phone]

[image: imessage activation second device pop up - email]

([Source](https://support.apple.com/en-gu/HT201349))